# TypeError : undefined is not a function when calling replace method

Tags: javascript

I know the code is very little and I'm missing something small.

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/0oa9006e/1/

code :

```
var veri = "+???+Girdiğiniz eposta adresi 'adfadf' geçersiz.-???-";

var a = veri.match(/\+[\?]*\+(.*)*\-[\?]*\-/g);
 a = a.replace(/[\+\-\?]*/g , "");
alert(a);
```

Comment: Arrays don't have a `replace` method.

Answer (score 1):

`String.match(param)` method returns an Array containing all matches. and array in javascript doesn't have `.replace method`. hence Error. You could try out something like:

```
 a = a.toString().replace(/[\+\-\?]*/g,""); // Array to string converstion
```

Answer (score 0):

Your match is returning an array, which doesn't have `replace`. Try:

```
a = a[0].replace(/[\+\-\?]*/g , "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var veri = "+???+Girdiğiniz eposta adresi 'adfadf' geçersiz.-???-";


var a = veri.match(/\+[\?]*\+(.*)*\-[\?]*\-/g);
// The variable 'a' is now an array.
// The first step in debugging is to always make sure you have the values
// you think you have.
console.log(a);

// Arrays have no replace method.
// Perhaps you are trying to access a[0]?
// or did you mean to modify `veri`?
 a = a.replace(/[\+\-\?]*/g , "");
alert(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

When `veri.match(/\+[\?]*\+(.*)*\-[\?]*\-/g)` is executed, your variable `a` is initialized to a JavaScript Array, which does not have a `replace` method.

Use a RegEx tool like [Regex101](http://regex101.com/) to see how your regular expression matches on the string `veri`, and then perform the `replace` operation on the appropriate element of that array.

Here's an example of your regular expression in use: http://regex101.com/r/hG3uI1/1

As you can see, your regular expression matches the entire string held by `veri`, so you want to perform the `replace` operation on the first (and only) element returned by `match`:

```
a = a[0].replace(/[\+\-\?]*/g , "");
```